# how can I execute a helper method function and run it in Docusaurus's markdown

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I have a file that contains Markdown:

```
# title example
example text that your mind has nothing to do with.
```

and I want to transform the text to uppercase.

is there any way to write a javascript function, then run it over the whole text of that markdown automatically?

the method as this case example is the `toUpperCase()`.

Comment: You can edit the docusaurus code to achieve that; but I don't understand your problem... You want *every text* in uppercase? Or just the title? Or some pages?

Comment: no, I am talking about running a code that will be executed over all files and all texts in my files.

Comment: can you guide me on what I should look for in the docusaurus code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if someone might need this, but here is some solutions I found out that can be applicable:

1. If you have a few files or a single file as an example that you want to run a method within it, you can use the `<script></script>` inside the `.mdx` file, like this :

   ```
    <script>
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    </script>
   ```

This will be executed when the documentation page loads.

2. if you want to execute some code across all your documentation pages, you can make a `serverMiddleware`, inside the **plugins** folder under your project directory, make as an example a `uppercase.js` file, then set your code like this:

   ```
    module.exports = {
     serverMiddleware: (app) => {
       app.use((req, res, next) => {
         res.on('finish', () => {
           const body = res._getData().toString().toUpperCase();
           res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body));
           res.end(body);
         });
         next();
       });
     },
   };
   ```

then declare that plugin inside the `docusaurus.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: ['uppercase'],
  // ...
}
```